# Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'. rxjs v6

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs6, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators

Since i was with angular9 and ivy compiler enable false.Everything was working fine.But after upgraded app to angular v10 and getting rxjs related operator and observable related getting compile error.

**Before**:

"rxjs": "^6.5.5",
"rxjs-compat": "^6.5.5"

**After**(now rxjs-compat removed):

"rxjs": "^6.6.2"

**Error:**

```
 error TS2339: Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'.
```

**Code:**

```
 let fromdate$ = of(fromdatevalue)
          let fromdateIfNull = fromdate$.filter(date => date != null)
            .map(date => {
              let fromdate = new Date(fromdatevalue);
              fromdate.setHours(8, 0, 0, 0);
              return fromdate;
            })
```

How to solve error and i want with properly use of `rxjs` import in angular v10 app.

Thanks.

Comment: I believe you want `pipe(filter(date => date !== null))`, where both pipe and filter are imported from rxjs

Comment: However, given that you are doing `of(fromdatevalue)` and you already have that value, I'm not sure why you are using an observable at all

Comment: @Taplar above given just sample code...but like that so many places i m getting above kind of error so ...i want with code and without code changes ...both case how to import observalbe/operator from rxjs.

Comment: It seems like you're using the old rxjs syntax. Why did you remove `rxjs-compat`? You need it to be able to do `.filter`.

Comment: @AliF50 yeah again added `rxjs-compat`...how to know about "..using the old rxjs syntax"...what is the best to know about wrong syntax?...in error component no filter import is available.

Comment: The new syntax is `.pipe(filter(...), map(...))`; and you import like `import { filter, map } from 'rxjs/operators';`. I think you need `rxjs 5 to 6` migration, I have to do it yet on the project I am working on. https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/v6/migration

Comment: ok understood...thanks.